# Group results by a factor column and weight results

Tags: group

I'm trying to group my results in the below results dataframe and weight them but get the error below. I really appreciate your help. thank you

```
results_grouped <- data.frame(
  CED = as.factor(cleaned_pc_data[, 4]),
  pred = round(predictions_pc_all, digits = 3),
  result = cleaned_pc_data$Voice_no_pp,
  diff = round(abs(predictions_pc_all - cleaned_pc_data$Voice_no_pp), digits = 3),
  weight_variable = cleaned_pc_data$Voice.n.polling.point.weight_ave
  
) %>%
  group_by(CED) %>% summarize (
    weighted_pred = weighted.mean(pred, w = cleaned_pc_data$Voice.n.polling.point.weight_ave),
    weighted_result = weighted.mean(result, w =cleaned_pc_data$Voice.n.polling.point.weight_ave),
    weighted_diff = weighted.mean(diff, w = cleaned_pc_data$Voice.n.polling.point.weight_ave)
  )
```

Error in `summarize()`:
ℹ In argument: `weighted_pred = weighted.mean(pred, w = cleaned_pc_data$Voice.n.polling.point.weight_ave)`.
ℹ In group 1: `CED = Adelaide`.
Caused by error in `weighted.mean.default()`:
! 'x' and 'w' must have the same length
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.